# Regex fails in C, online tests pass

Tags: c, regex

A regex that should work fails when I use it in C.

When I paste this regex here - https://regex101.com and test it it seems fine, as expected.

```
//clang 3.8.0

#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <regex.h>

int main(void)
{
   char    *regPatt = regPatt = "^HR(\\d{2})$";
   regex_t  regex;
   short    retval = regcomp (&regex, regPatt, 0);
   short    status = regexec (&regex, "HR16", (size_t) 0, NULL, 0);

   printf ("%hd", status);

   regfree (&regex);
}
```

So, online test work just fine.

Regex - ^HR(\d{2})$

String - HR16

At https://regex101.com for example, all is fine, I get a match.

In my code, it fails. Value printed with printf() is 1 (REG_NOMATCH).

edit - the code can be pasted for a test here: https://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_gcc

Comment: Minor note: Why are you using `char *regPatt = regPatt = "^HR(\\d{2})$";` instead of just `char *regPatt = "^HR(\\d{2})$";`? Why the extra `regPatt = `?

Comment: You're using basic regex (no REG_EXTENDED flag), so {2} is interpreted literally. Try `"^HR[0-9][0-9]$"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` and pass `REG_EXTENDED` to the `regcomp` function.

> `REG_EXTENDED`
>   Use POSIX Extended Regular Expression syntax when interpreting regex. If not set, POSIX Basic Regular Expression syntax is used.

Here is the [updated code](https://ideone.com/F9vuo6):

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <regex.h>

int main(void)
{
   char    *regPatt = regPatt = "^HR([0-9]{2})$";
   regex_t  regex;
   short    retval = regcomp (&regex, regPatt, REG_EXTENDED);
   short    status = regexec (&regex, "HR16", (size_t) 0, NULL, 0);
   printf ("%hd", status);
   regfree (&regex);
}
```

Comment: give the devil his due +1

Comment: I have used REG_EXTENDED and some other flags in my code and none of them changed the outcome. If I type it like this: [0-9][0-9] then is fine. [0-9]{2} fails. Go figure.

Comment: BTW, here is a [demo on the rextester](https://rextester.com/BJNIEE77596). Not sure you need it, but here is a [C code to extract Group 1 value](https://ideone.com/Wlw0eQ).

Comment: Tested your code, had to change one line, regmatch_t pmatch[2]; It seems to work, my compiler seem to be the problem. Might be an older version of gcc because it all works fine on the online compiler at https://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_gcc - I can accept your solution even though it didn't help me :(